# Bash: Is there a way to require the enter key to be pushed with read -n once character limit is reached?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to require the enter key to be pushed with read -n once character limit is reached, rather than automatically jumping to the following line in the script?

For example, in the following script:

```
echo "Please enter your credentials below" 
read -p "Please enter your username: " -e -n 15 usern
read -p "Please enter your password: " -s -e -n 15 passw
```

Once 15 chars are entered for the username, it automatically jumps to the password prompt. However, it would be more user-friendly to simply stop allowing input once the 15 chars are reached (besides the backspace key and enter key), and require the user to press enter to continue to the password prompt. This is how most logins work, after all...

I'm aware that I could use a while loop/if statement restricting the char limit in the usern variable (e.g. with -gt), but I was wondering how I could specifically limit the user to pressing either backspace or enter (or even the arrow keys if they want to edit a single character from their username, but I'm not worried about this right now), once those 15 characters are reached, and REQUIRE the user to press enter to continue to the following prompt.

Hopefully what I am asking for makes sense. Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: The `-n` option itself is already stretching what `read` is intended for. Shells aren't designed for writing polished user interfaces; they're meant to glue other languages together.

Comment: If you want to limit username to 15 chars, I'd recommend you allow the user to enter whatever they want then truncate it after.

Comment: Maybe with programs like `whiptail`. I guess with bash built-ins you'd get a very hacky solution if one at all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, bash's `read` isn't able to reproduce the expected behaviour for specific keys. However, you can avoid using `read` by rolling your own input parsing.

Some points to take into account:

- Terminal line settings need to be adjusted with `stty`, to avoid printing input characters as they are typed (i.e. we only want to print our messages, otherwise characters would be duplicated);
- Terminal emulator needs to support `VT100` escape codes, in order to erase the line and move the cursor when redrawing the prompt;
- Characters can be compared by ascii code, but when enter is pressed, we don't get a read character for the newline itself. However, since other whitespace characters are read, this is not an issue.

The following script implements the expected behaviour, by accepting characters up to a given limit (for the password, no typed characters are printed). The input is only submitted when enter is pressed.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

parse() {
  message=$1
  var=$2
  is_password=$3
  input=
  stty -icanon -echo
  while true; do
    # Clear line, move cursor to beginning, then print prompt
    if [ "$is_password" -eq 1 ]; then
      printf '\33[2K\r'"$message "
    else
      printf '\33[2K\r'"$message $input"
    fi
    # Read 1 character
    i=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)
    # Was a backspace read?
    if echo "$i" | grep -qP '\x7f'; then
      # Remove last character
      input=$(echo "$input" | sed 's/.$//')
    # Only add read character if input field limit wasn't reached
    elif [ ${#input} -lt 15 ]; then
      input=$input$i
    fi
    # Was a newline read?
    if [ -z "$i" ]; then
      break
    fi
  done
  stty icanon echo
  eval "$var=$input"
}

echo "Please enter your credentials below"
parse "Please enter your username:" "usern" 0
printf "\n%s\n" "Read username: $usern"
parse "Please enter your password:" "userp" 1
printf "\n%s\n" "Read password: $userp"
```